# .net framework compatibility from lower version to higher version

Tags: c#, .net

Can we build console application with target platform ".net Framework 4.5" and run on the Windows 10[in which already the .net 4.7.1 is installed] OR Can we build the console application with target platform ".net Framework 4.7.1" and run on the Windows 7[in which already the .net 4.5.1 is installed].

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The 2nd will most likely not work as it will require .net 4.7.1's runtime to be available... I think you will get the Initalization error when launching your app.

Comment: If i'am not mistaken it depends on a LOT of parameters, from one version to another depending on what sort of changes where made etc, everything could work, part of it, or almost none of your work could still be functionning.

Comment: Here is the link that may help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility

Comment: 4.5 to 4.7.1 will work 99.99% for you